# Attaching new device in linux only after password

Tags: privacy, hardware

Is there way to restrict attaching new devices in linux, so when attaching new device via usb, PCI, firewire and any other way, new device will be enabled only after entering password?

Comment: This is probably too broad. While it may be possible for some interfaces like USB (via udev), it is much more complicated for interfaces like PCIe.